# tcl fibonacci series in recursive

Tags: recursion, tcl, fibonacci

I have tried this not working ... Can anyone help please ? Want to know logic mistake or the syntax. Thanks in advance.

```
#*********************************************

puts "Fibbonocci sequence"

proc fibb {size} {
        if { $size == 1 || $size ==0 } {
                return $size
        } else {
                return [expr fibb [expr $size - 1] + fibb [expr $size - 2]]
        }

}
puts "Enter the length of the series:"

set n [gets stdin]

puts "Fibbonocci sequence upto $n terms are:"
puts [fibb $n]


#**********************************************
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
return [expr fibb [expr $size - 1] + fibb [expr $size - 2]]
```

Actually, that's got several problems. The first is that the expressions aren't braced:

```
return [expr { fibb [expr { $size - 1 }] + fibb [expr { $size - 2 }] }]
```

The second problem is that you have to call `fibb` as a Tcl command within that outer expression, so more `[`brackets`]` are needed:

```
return [expr { [fibb [expr { $size - 1 }]] + [fibb [expr { $size - 2 }]] }]
```

Plug that into the right place and the rest of your code should work…
But we can be more elegant than that by turning `fibb` into a function. Functions in Tcl are really just commands that live in the right namespace, `tcl::mathfunc`.

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::fibb {size} {
    if { $size == 1 || $size ==0 } {
        return $size
    }
    return [expr { fibb($size-1) + fibb($size-2) }]
}
```

Then you invoke it using, say:

```
puts [expr { fibb($n) }]
```

The *only* difference is that we've put the command (i.e., the procedure) in the right namespace so that it behaves as an expression component. And we've still put braces around the expression (please *always* do that until you at least understand why it matters) and simplified the code very slightly.

Also, you can still invoke it directly:

```
puts [tcl::mathfunc::fibb $n]
```

That'll work just the same way.